# How to bring the text of a textfield to the front of gradient background in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm rather new to swift.
I have three UItextFields  with gradient backgrounds. Because the background was not fixed to the size of field, I had to put the gradientSet in a  viewDidLayoutSubviews function. it was like that:

[image]
 Now size of background is almost ok, but another problem raised. The thing is when I'm typing inside the field, it does not show the text until I go to next field. How should I fix that? Additionally, please tell me what is wrong with the background of smallest field??
[image]

Part of my code is :

```
class phoneverify: UIViewController , UITextFieldDelegate{


@IBOutlet weak var studentNo: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var phoneNo: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var codeNo: UITextField!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let textfieldBorderColor = UIColor(red: 141/255, green: 231/255, blue: 201/255, alpha: 1)
        let barColor = UIColor(red: 73/255, green: 132/255, blue: 109/255, alpha: 1)

        phoneNo.layer.borderWidth = 3
        phoneNo.layer.borderColor = textfieldBorderColor.cgColor
        phoneNo.layer.cornerRadius = 6

        codeNo.layer.borderWidth = 3
        codeNo.layer.cornerRadius = 6
        codeNo.layer.borderColor = textfieldBorderColor.cgColor
        codeNo.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

        studentNo.layer.borderWidth = 3
        studentNo.layer.borderColor = textfieldBorderColor.cgColor
        studentNo.layer.cornerRadius = 6

        self.phoneNo.delegate = self
        self.studentNo.delegate = self
    }


    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        codeNo.setGradient(startColor:UIColor.gray, endColor: UIColor.white)
        phoneNo.setGradient(startColor:UIColor.gray, endColor: UIColor.white)
        studentNo.setGradient(startColor:UIColor.gray, endColor: UIColor.white)      
    }
extension UITextField {
    func setGradient(startColor:UIColor,endColor:UIColor) {
        let gradient:CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.colors = [startColor.cgColor, endColor.cgColor]
        gradient.frame = self.bounds
        gradient.cornerRadius = 6
        self.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gradient hides the text because you are adding the CAGradientLayer on top of all the other layers of the UITextField when you call `addSublayer`. It might work when using `insertSublayer(_:at:)` ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410944-insertsublayer)) to insert the layer below all other layers.

```
extension UITextField {
    func setGradient(startColor:UIColor,endColor:UIColor) {
        let gradient:CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.colors = [startColor.cgColor, endColor.cgColor]
        gradient.frame = self.bounds
        gradient.cornerRadius = 6
        self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
    }
}
```

The gradient extending outside of the text fields is because they do no automatically resize when the text field frame updates. Also, you are now adding a new gradient layer when the subviews are laid out.

To solve this, you can create a subclass of UITextField, override `layoutSubviews`, insert the gradient layer there if needed, and then adjust its size to match the bounds.

Comment: Thank you very much @Rengers , actually it did work, but with a bit of change, I had to put it like that:       `self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 1)    }`
So you may edit your answer and thank you again.

Comment: There is still a problem though, when I change the orientation to landscape, and then turn it back to portrait, the backgrounds go outside of the fields :( any ideas? @Rengers

Comment: That is because they do not resize automatically, and because you insert a new layer every time the subviews are laid out. I've edited the answer for some more info.